# Guide me implementing Oauth2 PHP server using thephpleague library

Tags: php, oauth, eloquent, slim, thephpleague

I am using `Slim Framework` With [`Eloquent ORM`](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database). Trying to implement https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server but I am totally confused how to do this. After adding this with composer, I created database with sql file provided in this package.

Now it is suggested to [implement Storage interfaces](http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/implementing-storage-interfaces/). I don't wanna do this, So I just copied storage classes found in Example Folder. I guess they should work as I am using same database right?

Also it is unclear how to initially seed the db. Here's my router where I am trying [`password`](http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant/) method.

```
$server = new \League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer;

$server->setSessionStorage(new SessionStorage);
$server->setAccessTokenStorage(new AccessTokenStorage);
$server->setClientStorage(new ClientStorage);
$server->setScopeStorage(new ScopeStorage);

$passwordGrant = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant();
$passwordGrant->setVerifyCredentialsCallback(function ($username, $password) {
    // implement logic here to validate a username and password, return an ID if valid, otherwise return false
    return 1;
});

$server->addGrantType($passwordGrant);

$app->post('/token',function() use ($server,$app){
    try{
        $response = $server->issueAccessToken();

        $res = $app->response();
        $res['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

        $res->body(json_encode($response));

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

       var_dump($e);
    }

});
```

I am totally frustrated whats happening. 
This throws following exception. [I have added scope `ok` in db]

```
object(League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\InvalidScopeException)[82]
  public 'httpStatusCode' => int 400
  public 'errorType' => string 'invalid_scope' (length=13)
  public 'serverShouldRedirect' => boolean true
  protected 'message' => string 'The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed. Check the "ok" scope.' (length=76)
  private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'code' => int 0
  protected 'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Grant\AbstractGrant.php' (length=77)
  protected 'line' => int 163
  private 'trace' (Exception) => 
    array (size=11)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Grant\PasswordGrant.php' (length=77)
          'line' => int 130
          'function' => string 'validateScopes' (length=14)
          'class' => string 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\AbstractGrant' (length=40)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\AuthorizationServer.php' (length=77)
          'line' => int 330
          'function' => string 'completeFlow' (length=12)
          'class' => string 'League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\PasswordGrant' (length=40)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      2 => 
        array (size=6)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\index.php' (length=31)
          'line' => int 67
          'function' => string 'issueAccessToken' (length=16)
          'class' => string 'League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer' (length=40)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          'function' => string '{closure}' (length=9)
          'args' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      4 => 
        array (size=4)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Route.php' (length=53)
          'line' => int 462
          'function' => string 'call_user_func_array' (length=20)
          'args' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      5 => 
        array (size=6)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Slim.php' (length=52)
          'line' => int 1326
          'function' => string 'dispatch' (length=8)
          'class' => string 'Slim\Route' (length=10)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      6 => 
        array (size=6)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\Flash.php' (length=64)
          'line' => int 85
          'function' => string 'call' (length=4)
          'class' => string 'Slim\Slim' (length=9)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      7 => 
        array (size=6)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride.php' (length=73)
          'line' => int 92
          'function' => string 'call' (length=4)
          'class' => string 'Slim\Middleware\Flash' (length=21)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      8 => 
        array (size=6)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions.php' (length=75)
          'line' => int 67
          'function' => string 'call' (length=4)
          'class' => string 'Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride' (length=30)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      9 => 
        array (size=6)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Slim.php' (length=52)
          'line' => int 1271
          'function' => string 'call' (length=4)
          'class' => string 'Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions' (length=32)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      10 => 
        array (size=6)
          'file' => string 'C:\wamp\www\linkshare\index.php' (length=31)
          'line' => int 131
          'function' => string 'run' (length=3)
          'class' => string 'Slim\Slim' (length=9)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array (size=0)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 is very challenging to understand and use correctly. In fact, the lead of OAuth 2.0 [famously walked away from the protocol after years of developing for it](http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/26/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/). According to Eran Hammer (the aforementioned lead developer):

> When compared with OAuth 1.0, the 2.0 specification is more complex,
> less interoperable, less useful, more incomplete, and most
> importantly, less secure.
>
> To be clear, OAuth 2.0 at the hand of a developer with deep
> understanding of web security will likely result is a secure
> implementation. However, at the hands of most developers – as has been
> the experience from the past two years – 2.0 is likely to produce
> insecure implementations.

So needless to say, there is some contention about OAuth 2.0. Alex Bilbie, the lead developer of the PHP League's OAuth 2.0-Server framework, appears to be one of the more knowledgeable developers for OAuth 2.0, although there are undoubtedly more. Still, keeping in mind one of Hammer's larger complaints - the lack of interoperability and completeness - you probably want to look for the following in an OAuth 2.0 implementation:

- Active development
- Full compliance with OAuth 2.0

I personally use and recommend Alex Bilbie's OAuth 2.0-Server, which now includes MAC bearer tokens and aims to be fully compliant. It is also under active development.

So, what does this mean for your project? Read up on the specifications. The package we are using claims to be fully compliant, which means that your best resource is [OAuth 2.0's specification](http://oauth.net/2/) itself. There is also decent documentation under the [PHP League website](http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/) that can help you with this particular implementation.

That being said, you may be missing the Scope for your client/user combination. The way OAuth2.0 is structured, your user needs to accept scopes that the client requests. That means that your "scopes" need to be linked in your other tables. If "OK" is not approved by a user (in the DB) then it will not be approved.

### Edit

Sounds like scopes are not the issue for you. This venue is not well suited for troubleshooting so I advise that you ensure you have the most current version of whatever framework you choose to use and report any bugs to the developer (with PHPLeague, it is via Github).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It will help me alot!

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but why was this comment being downvoted?

Comment: I hate this feature of SA... People can downvote with absolutely no response. Very passive aggressive and fails to help the questioner or the answerer. I edited my question and hopefully it addresses whatever people don't like.

Comment: @Mave Because it doesn't really answer the question. Anyone can copy-paste some text, point you to a book and the specs. The asker asked for guidance with what they had and not for some arbitrary "read this book" answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's been quite a few years since this question was asked, but here are links to OAuth2 libraries for Slim 3:

- https://github.com/chadicus/slim-oauth2-middleware
- https://packagist.org/packages/chadicus/slim-oauth2-routes