# Guide me implementing OAuth2 storage classes in thephpleague library

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, thephpleague

I am developing an oAuth 2.0 server using thephpleague library provided by Alex Bilbie. But, after the initializing the authorization server, when I declare the storage classes it throws an following error.

> "Fatal error: Class 'Storage\SessionStorage' not found"

Please help me to resolve this. I read your post about this problem here:- [Guide me implementing Oauth2 PHP server using thephpleague library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317300/guide-me-implementing-oauth2-php-server-using-thephpleague-library/28272280#28272280)

Please let me know how can I implement the storage classes. My current code:

```
require_once "/../vendor/autoload.php";
$server = new \League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer;
$server->setSessionStorage(new Storage\SessionStorage);
$server->setAccessTokenStorage(new Storage\AccessTokenStorage);
$server->setClientStorage(new Storage\ClientStorage);
$server->setScopeStorage(new Storage\ScopeStorage);
$server->setAuthCodeStorage(new Storage\AuthCodeStorage);
$authCodeGrant = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\AuthCodeGrant();
$server->addGrantType($authCodeGrant);
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I installed the library using composer and here is command:- "composer require league/oauth2-server".

Here is the path structure:- D:\wamp\www\demos\oAuth\oAuth2\vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\ "ALL LIBRARY CLASSES"

And 

Auload.php file path is:- D:\wamp\www\demos\oAuth\oAuth2\vendor\autoload.php

Answer (score 1):

The library that you use requires implementing your own storage classes, see http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/implementing-storage-interfaces/. The class names that you use are from an example implementation https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/tree/master/examples/relational/Storage that uses Capsule as its storage backend. If you want to use Capsule as you backend, you'll need to download those example implementation classes and install https://github.com/illuminate/database.

Comment: Sorry Hanz but i didn't get your answer. I put the Storage folder from https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/tree/master/examples/relational/Storage to my local directory but it still throw an error.

and Also, i tried to run the relational example. But, unfortunately it also throw this error.

Comment: they need to be in a `Storage` directory

Comment: Yes, here is my storage directory path:- D:\wamp\www\demos\oAuth\oAuth2\Storage\ ALL STORAGE CLASS